# Access to a pointer whose address is in a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to make a memdump function that with `fgets()` gets the address from the keyboard to dump and then, using this function prints the contents of that address in memory
I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_bytes(void *object, size_t size)
{
  char * bytes = object;
  size_t i;

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", bytes[i]);
  }
}

void CMD_Memdump(char* string){
    print_bytes(string, 200);   
}

int main(){
    char* str;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    CMD_Memdump(str);
}
```

I want to print the content of 0x7f3900e03000 that I have already ensured that is a valid address; the program prints on screen this:

```
0x7f3900e03000(garbage)
```

Why?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing what you store in the object.

Comment: C != C++. Choose one.

Comment: It's printing that because that's what your code is telling it to do.  What is your code that tries to read the corresponding memory?

Comment: first `fgets()` on `str` is wrong, no buffer allocated

Comment: Maybe you can use `strtoul` to convert the hex string to a ulong and then cast that to a void* or w/e.. then read the address..

Comment: `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` uses the value of an uninitialized variable (`str`); undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to you *bytes[i] instead of just bytes[i] :)

```
void print_bytes(void *object, size_t size)
{
  char * bytes = object;
  size_t i;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", *bytes[i]);  //<-Have you tried using *bytes[i] instead of 
                              //bytes[i]?
  }
}

void CMD_Memdump(char* string){
    print_bytes(string, 200);   
}

int main(){
    char* str;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    CMD_Memdump(str);
}
```

i hope i could help.

Comment: Where is the block of memory that `str` is pointing to? And `sizeof (str)` is just `sizeof (a pointer)` generally 8-bytes (4 on x86).

Comment: my general idea first was to make a char array for the str pointer in wich the input would be save and use sizeof(input) instead of sizeof(str)   but he said he got an adress as output so i thought it could work this way too and only asked if he tried to use *bytes instead of only bytes